# Heap Corruption Detected with find and replace program

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I have a find and replace program that works sometimes but then I started to get this error: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#142) at address.  CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

I am not too sure what the problem is because every time I allocated memory I also deallocated it. I must be missing something.  If anyone has any advice that would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code in full:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void optimize(char*, const char*, const char*);
bool oldStrValidate(char*, string);

int main()
{
string input, old_str, new_str;
bool oldStrValid = false;
string repeat;

do
{
    cout<<"Enter a string: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,input);
    char* inputPtr = new char[input.length() +1];
    strcpy(inputPtr, input.c_str());



    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter the section of the string you wish to replace."<<endl;
        getline(cin, old_str);
        oldStrValid = oldStrValidate(inputPtr, old_str);
    }while(oldStrValid == false);
    cout<<"What would you like to replace\"" <<old_str<<"\" with?"<<endl;
    getline(cin,new_str);
    char* oldPtr = new char[old_str.length() +1];
    strcpy(oldPtr, old_str.c_str());
    char* newPtr = new char[new_str.length() +1];
    strcpy(newPtr, new_str.c_str());
    optimize(inputPtr, oldPtr, newPtr);
    cout<<"          try again? \"y\" for yes or \"n\" to quit." << endl;
    cout<<"          : ";
    cin>>repeat;
    cin.ignore();
    delete [] inputPtr;
    delete [] oldPtr;
    delete [] newPtr;
}while(repeat == "y");

return 0;
  }


void optimize( char* input_str, const char* old_str, const char* new_str  )
{
string input_string(input_str);
string old_string(old_str);
string new_string(new_str);
size_t position = 0;

while ((position = input_string.find(old_string, position)) != string::npos)
{
  input_string.replace( position, old_string.length(), new_string );
  position += new_string.length();
}

strcpy(input_str, input_string.c_str());
cout << input_string << endl;
}
bool oldStrValidate(char* str, string searchFor)
{
string input(str);
int position = 0;

while ((position = input.find(searchFor, position)) != string::npos)
    return true;

{
    cout<<"the substring you enterd does not exist within the string"<<endl;
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Why so many copying of strings? Yikes!

Comment: "Every time I allocated memory I also deallocated it."  That's terrific, but that's not what the heap corruption error is complaining about.  It says:  **"CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."**

Answer (score 2):

You may want to think about what will happen when you enter the string `"a"` and then replace `a` with something like `this string is way too long`.

You'll find that, while C++ strings handle expansion quite well, the same cannot be said for C strings. When you execute this line:

```
strcpy(input_str, input_string.c_str());
```

the expanded string is copied in to the (very much non-expanded) `input_str` buffer, hence your heap corruption.

The whole *point* of C++ strings is to prevent the problems a lot of people have with the more primitive C strings, so I'm not entirely certain why you're reverting to the old methods. You're far better off using C++ strings everywhere. Otherwise you have to make sure you manage the space yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's being caused by you replacing a small string with a larger one that you don't have room for -- specifically corrupting the heap at this line in `optimize()`:

`strcpy(input_str, input_string.c_str());`

Comment: Per the function name that is obviously an optimization: why allocate more memory if you don't need (want) to?! :D